# Status bar: how to detect touch events?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsstatusitem

I've successfully added a *NSStatusItem* to the menu bar, showing an regular *NSMenu*.

Is it possible to capture a hover event on this and in that case, display a different menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new custom view, override method [NSView mouseEntered:] with [NSView addTrackingRect:...]  and then set to the status item [NSStatusItem setView:]